# Functions with custom type in header

Tags: c, function, types

I've written a program that uses three functions to which I pass a custom type defined as:

```
typedef struct w 
{
    char *wd;
    long position;
    struct w *next;
}W;
typedef W *word;
```

When I try to put the functions in a header file like this:

```
void find(char *s,word *T);
void seek(char *s,word p);
void look(word p);
```

and try to compile the file I get

> error: unknown type name ‘word’

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why? why you call your structure `w`???????? What does it mean? Just DONT DO THAT, don't `typedef` the pointer.

Comment: You need to have the declaration (at least) of `word` before you use it.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. More specifically, where do you have your type-alias declarations, and where do you have your function prototypes in relation to the type-aliases?

Comment: Do not `typedef` pointers! This obfuscates code and will eventually cause missunderstanding lateron.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this?

```
typedef struct w
{
    char *wd;
    long position;
    struct w *next; 
}word;
```

or

```
#define word w

typedef struct w
{
    char *wd;
    long position;
    struct w *next; 
};
```